# How do I not use the web part of Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I don't need the web part (for now), the objective is to make an ORM, django has to be a kafka consumer to receive and send to the postregres database

I read the docs, but I didn't understand how not to use the web part

struct:
[image]

code (kafka_consumer.py):

```
import pickle
from django.shortcuts import render
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import environ

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# def process_message(message: str) -> None:
#     print(f"message -- {message}")


# class KafkaService:
#   @staticmethod
#   def kafka_consumer():
#     consumer = KafkaConsumer(env("KAFKA_TOPIC"), bootstrap_servers=env("KAFKA_URI"), group_id="test")
#     for message in consumer:
#       process_message(message)

# Create your views here.
def cons():
  consumer = KafkaConsumer(env("KAFKA_TOPIC",
                           bootstrap_servers=[env("KAFKA_URI")],
                           api_version=(0,10))
  
  for message in consumer:
    deserialized_data = pickle.loads(message.value)
    print(deserialized_data)

cons()
```

code settings.py:

```
import environ

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': env("DB_NAME"), 
        'USER': env("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("DB_HOST"), 
        'PORT': env("DB_PORT"),
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's structured correctly, just follow the official doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: You can define a custom Django management command for this.

Comment: how do you do this? I already tried `python kafka_consumer.py`

Comment: you can certainly do this, but if you don't want the web part why not use another ORM that's just an ORM ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Take a look at the package(https://github.com/dancaron/Django-ORM) to see if it helps

Comment: @Anentropic
I tried to do it with golang gorm, but it doesn't migrate a table with a change, for example: there is a change to a table of its own, but if I don't change the code it can cause several errors and duplications.

Comment: @Sam you can integrate other tools with GORM for versioned migrations. For example its [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Atlas-Integration) suggests [atlas as one such tool](https://atlasgo.io/guides/orms/gorm)

Comment: @Sam how about sqlalchemy and alembic in python? If you use flask, you could leverage on flask-sqlalchemy and flask-migrate to manage your database for you.

Comment: @Anentropic: given I understand it correctly, one might later add a web interface, or take advantage of Django's migration tooling. Some projects have separated the Django ORM, so it is possible, and the advantage is to keep the number of (different) ORM sytnaxes down.